# Is there a JPA annotation equivalent of jackson's @JsonAnyGetter/@JsonAnySetter?

Tags: jpa, jooq

With jackson, I can use `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` to serialize/deserialize a `Map<String, Object>` into extra fields of a json object.  Is there a JPA annotation that will do similar things with extra db column values being get/set from/into a member `Map`?

Specifically, I'd like to use jooq's `.fetchInto(Pojo.class)` to hydrate a java object.  I can manually use `.fetch(RecordMapper<Record, Pojo>)` to get the results I want by hydrating the `Map` member from the Record fields manually, but wondering if there's a more automatic way of doing this.  Pojo code could look something like the following (use lombok's `@Data` to make it concise):

```
@Data
public class Pojo {
    @Column("field1")
    private int field1;

    @Column("field2")
    private String field2;

    @JsonAnyGetter // works for json serialization,
    @JsonAnySetter // is there an equivalent for JPA?
    private Map<String, Object> extraFields;
}
```

Comment: Since JPA does not "serialise" / "deserialise" then the answer to that would be a no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can register a [`RecordMapperProvider`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/RecordMapperProvider.html) with your jOOQ configuration in order to override how various methods, including `fetchInto(Class)` apply mapping:
https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.11/manual/sql-execution/fetching/pojos-with-recordmapper-provider/

Comment: Right, I still need to write my own `RecordMapper` though, there's not one (or a way to configure the `DefaultRecordMapper`) that will do everything `DefaultRecordMapper` does plus put values of "extra" columns into a Map of the mapped class, right?

Comment: Your record mapper can delegate to the `DefaultRecordMapper` and "fix" things after mapping.